# Error in thrid-party Makefile made with Cygwin

Tags: c++, makefile, cygwin

I am trying to compile a third-party c++ project that says it is intended for 64 bit Ubuntu with cygwin on my windows pc and am encountering the following error when making the project:

```
BuildPrefix.mak:212: *** Invalid configuration Unable to determine compiler version..  Stop.
```

I'm pretty sure it's the makefile that is throwing this error but I'm not sure exactly why or how to fix it. The makefile is pretty large but here is the lines that are throwing the errors:

```
# Validate we built the same as we received. Anything else is invalid.
ifneq ($(ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS),$(__ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS_VALIDATION))
  $(error Invalid configuration $(CFG))
endif
```

which comes after it doing a bunch of stuff that I'm not sure whats going on:

```
# Optional options field?
```

ifeq ($(CFG_LIST_LENGTH),5)
    ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS := $(call word,4,$(CFG_LIST))
    ACTIV_CONFIGURATION_TYPE := $(call word,5,$(CFG_LIST))

```
# C++11?
ifneq ($(call findstring,cxx11,$(ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS)),)
    ACTIV_CXX11 := 1
    __ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS_VALIDATION := $(call merge,-,$(__ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS_VALIDATION) cxx11)
endif

# STLport?
ifneq ($(call findstring,stlport,$(ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS)),)
    IS_STLPORT := 1
    __ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS_VALIDATION := $(call merge,-,$(__ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS_VALIDATION) stlport)
endif

# vstring?
ifneq ($(call findstring,vstring,$(ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS)),)
    ACTIV_STRING_IMPLEMENTATION := vstring
    __ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS_VALIDATION := $(call merge,-,$(__ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS_VALIDATION) $(ACTIV_STRING_IMPLEMENTATION))
endif

# libc++?
ifneq ($(call findstring,libcxx,$(ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS)),)
    __ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS_VALIDATION := $(call merge,-,$(__ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS_VALIDATION) libcxx)
    ACTIV_LIBCXX := 1
endif

# Boost string?
ifneq ($(call findstring,bstring,$(ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS)),)
    ACTIV_STRING_IMPLEMENTATION := bstring
    __ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS_VALIDATION := $(call merge,-,$(__ACTIV_BUILD_OPTIONS_VALIDATION) $(ACTIV_STRING_IMPLEMENTATION))
endif
```

Theres a lot more to the file so let me know if I should post more, any hints/clues/possible courses of action would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"... that says it is intended for 64 bit Ubuntu with **cygwin on my windows pc** ..."_ Well, good luck :-/ ... (Did you consider simply to use a suitable Ubuntu VMWare image?)

Comment: There are two possibilities: In the best case, you are just missing some cygwin packages that the 3rd party needs in order to build.  In that case, you might fix it just by installing more stuff in your cygwin.  The second possibility is that the 3rd party build is actually incompatible with cygwin.  In that case, you're best shot is probably to get support from the 3rd part provider.

Comment: It's not clear why you would expect this to work at all. You might get some help if you could say *what* library you're trying to build.